# Selenium and Java: invalid or illegal selector

Tags: java, selenium

Either I'm blind, or something else is wrong. I keep getting "invalid or illegal selector" when trying to access a WebElement in the same way as I've done a thousand times.

The markup:

```
<label translate="" class="hb-label-tekst" for="0-erBarnetrygdRiktig-ja">Ja</label>
```

The Java/selenium code:

```
@FindBy(css = "[for=0-erBarnetrygdRiktig-ja]")
WebElement erBarnetrygdRiktigJa0;
```

Error message:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I usually get this error when I put brackets in the wrong place, but this seems to be correctly formed. Can someone spot the error?

Comment: Did you try `@FindBy(css = "[for='0-erBarnetrygdRiktig-ja']")` (with single quote)?

Comment: Hey. That actually worked. Strange. I've never had to do that before.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with css selector, I mean **for** tag is not a css attribute to be used. Instead you can try using xpath in this case that will look like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//label[@for = '0-erBarnetrygdRiktig-ja']")
WebElement erBarnetrygdRiktigJa0;
```

Comment: Yes, that's a point. However, it's really annoying when it works most of the time and then suddenly not. And I really, really don't like relying on xpath for finding elements.

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the drawbacks on selenium changes in some element will make your code fail. And about xpath try using relative xpath they will be helpful most of the times.